# HTML 5 Canvas Cards Game

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am making a real time cards game in HTML 5 canvas. The backend server is **node.js**. Designing the cards table is giving me a hard time, because I just don't want to draw everything on canvas.

*This is something I want to achieve for the cards table*. [image]

One option I have right now is to make this image as the background of the canvas and animate my cards over it. This is good for **performance point of view**, but then I may not be able to capture events like **cards moved in a particular area**.

> What is the best way to solve this situation? Should I set it as
>   background of canvas, or create it over canvas with css?

**FYI: I am using kineticjs as a front-end framework for developing this game.**

Comment: Have you thought about using the click events on the canvas? Or does that not work together with kineticJS?

Comment: @Sam KineticJS has click events.

Comment: KineticJS does have click, drag and many other events. My point here is that, how would I know if a card entered a particular area, like "Crystal Deck" if I were animating them over a background image of table?

Comment: So I'd use the background as an image and click events like onmousedown/onmouseup/onmousemove to determine what actions the user does where/when. Problem is: you don't get around math and some "else if"-mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which cell the mouse is over like this:

- Listen for `dragmove` events which fire when the card is being dragged.
- Inside the dragmove handler, get the mouse position,
- Mathematically calculate which cell the mouse is over

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/DN5hA/

Here's how it might look in code:

```
card1.on("dragmove",function(){
    var mouse=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var cellX=parseInt((mouse.x-borderOffsetX)/cellWidth);
    var cellY=parseInt((mouse.y-borderOffsetY)/cellHeight);
    highlight.position({
        x:borderOffsetX+cellX*cellWidth,
        y:borderOffsetY+cellY*cellHeight
    });
    layer.draw();
});


});
```

Comment: I must say that is the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of KineticJS and I love it's layers, which may be of interest to you.
Each layer is it's own canvas/SVG, meaning that updating one layer doesn't cause the others to be redrawn.
Thus, you can have one layer in the background for the board, while having other layers for the game mechanics.

Comment: I am well aware of the layers. My point actually is that I need to know if a card traverses from one cell to another (an event needs to be generated when this occurs). Incase of a background image, I won't be a be to capture these events. This is my point of view. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How about floating div's over the whole canvas and listening for onmouseout/onmouseover events? Would that get in conflict with the canvas events? If so, could you pass the events to the canvas manually?